# C++ multidimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm new to c++ and its developing. i used

```
static const int ipx[7][2] = { {-1, 0}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 1}, {-2, 0}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {0, 0} };
```

and when i prints the values of that array i got results as follows. could  anyone please explain why this happens. Thank you

```
printf("-> %i \n",ipx[3][1]); // prints -> 0
printf("-> %i \n",ipx[7][1]); //prints-> 28 
printf("-> %i \n",ipx[7][0]); //prints ->-> 1 
printf("-> %i \n",ipx[5][1]);  //prints -> 1
```

thank you in any advance.

Answer (score 4):

C++ arrays are 0-indexed, so printing out `ipx[7][0]` is undefined behaviour since the indices run `0..6` for a 7-element array. You probably wanted `ipx[2][1]`, `ipx[6][1]`, `ipx[6][0]`, and `ipx[4][1]`.

Comment: how did i get printf("-> %i \n",ipx[7][1]); to value 28 could you please explain more .than you.

Comment: You are accessing unalocated memory : undefined bahaviour

Answer (score 1):

Basicly, if you declare a array with 7 "slots" you have slots 0-6 available.